# push_back operation in c# containers

Tags: c#, c++, list, stack, push-back

I need container like c++ vector. Often it is adviced to use List, but it dosen't support push_back operation. I know this is rather simple implementing an extension method for List container. But. Would Stack be a good alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't Add method of list suit your purpose?
A vector is a fifo whereas a stack is filo. They are quite distinct

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It does support [`List<T>.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks! Because I thought it corresponds to push_front

Answer (score 2):

You won't get a direct equivalent to `vector` in C# because you have no control over how the memory is allocated.  `std::vector` will always have its memory in a contiguous block; so if needed, you could access it like so:

```
std::vector<int> v;
// add items to v
CallSomeCFunction(&v[0]);
```

C# gives you no control over how the memory is allocated, so the distinction between a vector/array and a list is non-existent.  You can use the `List` container is what you want.

Comment: Actually, I believe ArrayList<> is stored in contiguous memory.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx - I've never seen anything stating that in any previous documentation either.  With the way the GC works, it would be almost impossible to enforce.